# Angular.js / Ng.select with ng.value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select:

```
  <select selected="windows" ng-model="wdtype[4][$index]" id="inputEmail1" class="form-control">
       <option>app1</option>
       <option>app2</option>
       <option>app3</option>
  </select>
```

I want that every time that the user select option, the field `inputName3` will be reflected. The field defines like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="wdname[4][$index]" id="inputName3" placeholder="Machine Name" disabled>
```

For example, the user select `app1`, so the name will be `m-app1`. If the user select `app2`, the name will be displayed: `m-app2`.

I don't see any trigger in angular which can help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can define values for options like this

```
   <option value="m-app1">app1</option>
   <option value="m-app2">app2</option>
   <option value="m-app3">app3</option>
```

Or make it in a generic way. Define a function in scope that transforms selected value the way you need.

In controller:

```
$scope.getMachineName = function () {
   if (wdtype[4][$index]) return '';
   return 'm-' + $scope.wdtype[4][$index];
}
```

In template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{getMachineName()}}"
```